# ASP.NET - customizing windows authentication login controls

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, authentication

I just wonder if customizing windows authentication login pop up is possible like adding another control such as dropdown instead of just built in username/password textboxes.

Comment: @Camilo, i wouldn't raise this question if there's clear answer out there.

Comment: I already done a research and none of it is clear to what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: @Camilo Terevinto, if you just downvoted me because of thinking I did no research, you should have atleast provide me a link of sample article to what I'm looking for though.

Comment: what do you mean you have done research? if you are using textboxes for username / password what is stopping you from using a dropdown also what would the dropdown list represent.. you have a poorly written question and I am quite sure others will follow suite in regards to downvoting. please edit / update the question to provide more detail in regards to what it is you are wanting to accomplish in the long run..?

Comment: @MethodMan - apologies for the poorly written post  I made. however, are we in the same thinking about the windows authentication? the pop up that is displaying on start up? the username/password textboxes is built in to it and I'm having problem because I can't figure how I could add a dropdown to it. I tried looking for how to implement it but failed to find that suites to my searching. btw, I'm thinking to make dropdown as list of country code.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think Windows allowed or provide any API to let the web developer implement their custom control in windows authentication.

You can implement your own login page like this person does in Sharepoint http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chunliu/archive/2010/09/21/creating-a-custom-login-page-for-windows-authentication.aspx